# How can I orderByChild on Android Firebase chat based application?

Tags: android, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I'm trying to build a user to user chat application, but I'm not able to order the chat list by last message sent.

My Firebase (real time) structure is like this:

[image: Structure]

I'm trying to retrieve the data like this, but i'm not able to order by "timestamp" in the inner message.

```
final String uID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages");
ref.orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(uID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

Did anyone knows how can I order the list of users by the timestamp of the last message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the query to the following:

```
final String uID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages");
ref.child(uID_uID).orderByChild("timestamp").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

You need access to the direct node under the node `Messages`, the node with underscore. Then you can add `orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo("157644739279")`

Comment: But I can not acces to this child (uID_uID) because in my database the first ID is the user who is sending the message and the second one is the user who receive the message, so I always get a null on that query.